# How do I deselect the Housing Tools?

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, which I just started playing it seems to be hanging on the "Housing Query" tool.  Once I select it, I can't select anything else unless I completely exit the game.  What can I do to deselect it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pressing the right-click button on your mouse should get rid of the cursor. If you're talking about the icon that appears in the menu screen, click on the small house icon on the right side of the inventory screen again to get rid of it.